# Index of the number with the lowest real part, of a complex number

Tags: matlab, complex-numbers

I have a problem with some complex numbers, which I rarely work with.
My problem is that I have an array with made by 
`cos^(-1)(x)` where `x` can be values smaller or larger than `|1|`, thereby getting some complex numbers, I need the index of the number with the lowest real part.

the data could look like

```
[0 + 0.37i, 0 + 0.18i,  0.2 + 0.0i, 0.3 + 0.0i, 0.4 + 0.0i]
```

so I need the index of `0.2 + 0.0i`

what I have tried so far is

```
[val_min_x,idx_min_x]=min(real(x)>0))
```

since I need the smallest value of the real part larger then zero.
But this wont work and I guess its because `real(x>0)` gives out true or false. And then taking the minimum of that just gives the index of the first zero.

Any suggestions to solve this without an if statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First convert all 0s to 1s, so that min() will not find them (by addition of 1). Then keep everything else untouched (by addition of 0). A boolean trick will keep everything in one line for brevity,

Thanks @CG

```
% example input
A=[0 + 0.37i, 0 + 0.18i, 0.2 + 0.0i, 0.3 + 0.0i, 0.4 + 0.0i]
% leveraging maximum cos(x)<=1 and boolean true being cast to 1
[~, idx] = min(real(A)+(real(A)==0))


A =

  Columns 1 through 3

   0.0000 + 0.3700i   0.0000 + 0.1800i   0.2000 + 0.0000i

  Columns 4 through 5

   0.3000 + 0.0000i   0.4000 + 0.0000i


idx =

     3
```

Comment: It works brilliantly!! thanks!. So just to understand, real(x)==0 makes an array of 0 and 1, then you add the real(x) to that and find the minimum? it works but I cant seem to understand why?

Comment: Well the idea is to convert all 0s to 1s, so that min() will not find them (by addition of 1), and keep everything else untouched (by addition of 0). The boolean trick keeps everything in 1 line for brevity, surely you could expanded it for clearness.

Comment: `[~, idx] = min(real(A)+(real(A)==0))`. No need to use loops (`arrayfun` is a disguised loop), when performing the same operation on all elements in a matrix.

Comment: @CG. That's right. Now is much less stinky. Thanks bro.